# FactoryGirl create_list with different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to user FactoryGirl to create a list of items, but I need the items to not be in order. This is what I have, but I would like it to be DRYer.

*spec.rb*

```
context "three out of order" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:thing, ordering: 3)
    FactoryGirl.create(:thing, ordering: 1)
    FactoryGirl.create(:thing, ordering: 2)
  end

   it "should sort the things in order" do
    expect(Thing.all.map(&:ordering)).to eq([1, 2, 3])
   end
end
```

I know that you can create multiple items with:

```
   FactoryGirl.create_list(:thing, ordering: 3 )
```

but I wanted to create items so it tested their order, and they would create all of them in order since I have sequence set up in the factory.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
before do
  (1..3).to_a.shuffle.each do |order|
    FactoryGirl.create(:thing, ordering: order)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a classic case of solving the problem, but not answering the question. Obviously that could be done, it's very much like the original example, but the goal here is the user `create_list` and to keep it simpler. The question was not "How can I create three model with different names", but rather "Can I use create_list to create three models with different names", which unfortunately is not possible.